# How to use nested attributes in yii2?

Tags: mongodb, yii2, nested-attributes

How can I define mongodb nested attributes in yii2? and display it in index GridView?

Sample collection :

[image]

This is my model :

```
public function attributes()
{
    return [
        '_id',
        ....
        'approved',
        'Userbanks', //How to define this nested attribute?
        'createdAt',
        'updatedAt',
    ];
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [[''createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'requestStatus', 'approved', 
            'Userbanks'// here ?
         ], 'safe']
        ];
}
```

In my GridView :

```
[
            'format' => 'raw',
            'label' => 'Withdrawer',
            'attribute' => 'Userbanks{accountholdername}', //How to get accountholdername here
],
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way as using relational databases:
You need create the all different models and next write the relations.

I recommend to you read the gii generator  from Yii2 and Mongo DB  i think it be usefull for you . [Here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb)

This is your  model :

```
/**
* @property Userbanks[] $userbanks    
* @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
*/
public function getUserbanks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Userbanks::className(),['_id'=>'user_id']);// your relation ids
}
```